# Spring AOP @Before advice return value

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm new with Spring AOP and I was wondering if it is possible to return a value from `@Before` to method and use this variable inside it, for example:

```
@Before("@annotation(CheckUserReservationPermission) && args(username,idReservation)")
public Reservation userCreationAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, String username, Integer idReservation) throws Throwable {
    Reservation reservation = reservationServices.findById(idReservation);
    if (!reservation.getUser().getUsername().equals(username))
        throw new PermissionException("You can't delete the reservation with id: " + idReservation);
    return reservation;
}
```

and my method:

```
@Override
@CheckUserReservationPermission
public void deleteReservationById(String username, Integer idReservation) throws QueryException {
    synchronized(ReservationsSchedulerServicesImpl.class){
        databaseReservationServices.deleteReservationById(username, reservation);  
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make this? Otherwise I have to repeat the query.
Thanks

***UPDATE***: With `@Around` I may have this code, but how can I retrieve the variable into `deleteReservationById` method?

```
@Around("@annotation(CheckUserReservationPermission) && args(username,idReservation)")
public Object userCreationAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, String username, Integer idReservation) throws Throwable {
    Reservation reservation = reservationServices.findById(idReservation);
    if (!reservation.getUser().getUsername().equals(username))
        throw new PermissionException("You can't delete the reservation with id: " + idReservation);
    return pjp.proceed(new Object[] {reservation});
}
```

Comment: can we use around advice ?

Comment: No you cannot. You can only return a value from an around advice.

Comment: and with an around advice I can use the variable with the method?

Comment: @luca here we are sending argument to target method "deleteReservationById", So signature need to be changed to accept Reservation

Comment: @luca plz check updated answer

Comment: I understand, it can only change parameter value so I should provide all parameters to the method. Thanks

Comment: you understood right welcome

Comment: Please post a new question instead of appending it to the existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2:**

1. Advice

   ```
   @Around("@annotation(CheckUserReservationPermission) && args(username,idReservation)")
   public Object userCreationAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, DeleteByIdRequest req) throws Throwable {
       Reservation reservation = reservationServices.findById(idReservation);
       if (!reservation.getUser().getUsername().equals(username)) {
           throw new PermissionException("You can't delete the reservation with id: " + idReservation);}

        req.setReservation(reservation);  
       return pjp.proceed(new Object[] {req});
   ```

   }

2.
 New Request POJO

```
 class DeleteByIdRequest {
      Reservation reservation;
      String username;
      Integer idReservation;
    }
```

3.Target Method

```
@Override
@CheckUserReservationPermission
public void deleteReservationById(DeleteByIdRequest request) throws QueryException {
    synchronized(ReservationsSchedulerServicesImpl.class){
        databaseReservationServices.deleteReservationById(username, reservation);  
    }
}
```

See the interfaces of this advices,

check what they return.

1.ThrowsAdvice

```
public void afterThrowing(IllegalArgumentException e) throws Throwable {
}
```

2.AfterReturningAdvice

```
public void afterReturning(Object returnValue, Method method,
        Object[] args, Object target) throws Throwable {
}
```

3.MethodBeforeAdvice

```
public void before(Method method, Object[] args, Object target)
        throws Throwable {

}
```

4.MethodInterceptor (Around Advice)

```
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {

}
```

If you note in 4th point **only Around advice is returning object.**

you have to define the joinPoint.proceed() to control when should the interceptor return the control to the original method.

Check simple example [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/)

**EDIT:**
I think this can be achieved with help of [proceeding with arguments](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-proceeding-with-the-call) 

Basically you can then call proceed() with the new arguments.

Comment: I was looking about `@Around` but how can I send `reservation` to my method?

Comment: do you mean , how to handle this object in your deleteReservationById() method?

Comment: Yes this is how I worked, but my method how can catch the variable?